# Need assistance in calculating Due Date using SQL Server Functions

Tags: sql-server, sqldatetime

Am trying to calculate due date using invoice date by the following constraints

- will have two text boxes one is to enter day of the month and another is to enter the day before due month
- if the day of the month is 4 and day before due month is 5 we have to calculate the values by subtracting 4 and 5 if the subtracted value is -ve 1 and if the invoice date entered is 11/13/2016 so that the due date must be 12/04/2017 (here 04 is the day of month)
- if the day of the month is 15 and day before due month is 5 and the subtracted value is 10 (not negative) the invoice date entered is 11/13/2016 means the due date must be 12/15/2016 (here 15 is the day of month) if the invoice date is less than or equal to subtracted value ie 10 like invoice date 11/09/2016 then the invoice date must be 11/15/2016

Note the above constraints must also satisfy the leap year while calculating the fue dates

Please help me am new bee to SQL server functions

The Code which I have Tried

```
DECLARE  @INVOICEDATE DATETIME ='02/01/2016'
        ,@TENANTID BIGINT=29
        ,@PAYMENTTERMID BIGINT=2

BEGIN
    DECLARE @DUEDATE DATETIME
    DECLARE @ACTUALDUEDATE BIGINT
    DECLARE @CALCULATEDDATE DATETIME
    DECLARE @PAYMENTTYPES BIGINT
    DECLARE @DAYSOFMONTH BIGINT
    DECLARE @DAYSAFTERDUEDAY BIGINT
    DECLARE @NOOFDAYS BIGINT

    SELECT @PAYMENTTYPES = PAYMENT_TYPES
        ,@NOOFDAYS = NUMBER_OF_DAYS
        ,@DAYSOFMONTH = DAY_OF_MONTH
        ,@DAYSAFTERDUEDAY = DAYS_AFTER_DUE_DAY
        FROM XC_PAYMENT_TERMS_MASTER
        WHERE TENANT_ID = @TENANTID
        AND PAYMENT_TERM_ID = @PAYMENTTERMID 

    IF @PAYMENTTYPES = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @CALCULATEDDATE = DATEADD(dd, @NOOFDAYS, @INVOICEDATE)
    END
    ELSE IF @PAYMENTTYPES = 2
    BEGIN
        SET @ACTUALDUEDATE = @DAYSOFMONTH - @DAYSAFTERDUEDAY
            IF 1 = (
            IIF(DATEPART(dd, (
                        EOMONTH(CONCAT (
                                DATEPART(yyyy, @INVOICEDATE)
                                ,'0201'
                        ))
                )) = 29, 1, 0)
            )
            --LEAP YEAR
            BEGIN
            IF(@ACTUALDUEDATE <= 0)
            BEGIN
            IF DATEPART(dd, @INVOICEDATE) = 30
            AND  DATEPART(mm, @INVOICEDATE) =01
            BEGIN
            SET @CALCULATEDDATE=DATEADD(dd, 31, @INVOICEDATE)
            END
            ELSE IF DATEPART(dd, @INVOICEDATE) = 31
            AND  DATEPART(mm, @INVOICEDATE) =01
            BEGIN
            SET @CALCULATEDDATE=DATEADD(dd, 31, @INVOICEDATE)
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
            IF @DAYSOFMONTH = 30 OR @DAYSOFMONTH =31
            BEGIN
            SET @CALCULATEDDATE= DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0, @INVOICEDATE)+2,0))
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
            DECLARE @NEWNEGATIVEDATE DATETIME
            SET @NEWNEGATIVEDATE = DATEADD(DAY, @DAYSOFMONTH - DATEPART(DAY, @INVOICEDATE), @INVOICEDATE);
            SET @DUEDATE = DATEADD(mm, 1, @NEWNEGATIVEDATE)
            END
            END
            END
            ELSE IF(@ACTUALDUEDATE > 0)
            BEGIN
            SELECT 2
            DECLARE @COMBINEDDATE DATETIME
            SET @COMBINEDDATE=DATEADD(DAY, @ACTUALDUEDATE - DATEPART(DAY, @INVOICEDATE), @INVOICEDATE);
            SELECT @INVOICEDATE AS INVDATE 
            SELECT @COMBINEDDATE AS COMBDATE
            IF @INVOICEDATE > @COMBINEDDATE
            BEGIN
            SELECT 115 AS TRUE
            DECLARE @NEWDATE DATETIME
            SET @NEWDATE = DATEADD(DAY, @DAYSOFMONTH - DATEPART(DAY, @INVOICEDATE), @INVOICEDATE);
            SET @DUEDATE = DATEADD(mm, 1, @NEWDATE)
            SELECT @DUEDATE AS DATES
            END

            ELSE 
            BEGIN
            SET @DUEDATE=DATEADD(DAY, @DAYSOFMONTH - DATEPART(DAY, @INVOICEDATE), @INVOICEDATE);
            SELECT @DUEDATE AS DATEDUE
            END

            END
            END
            ELSE 
            --NOT LEAP YEAR
            BEGIN

            END

        END
        END
```

Comment: How about you show us what you have tried in order to solve this, then we will help you. Edit the question, and add the SQL you have thus far.

Comment: @R.Richards please see the code in edited post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Solved it by creating the following functions

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[XC_CALCULATE_DUE_DATE] (
    @INVOICEDATE DATETIME
    ,@TENANTID BIGINT
    ,@PAYMENTTERMID BIGINT
    )
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DAYOFMONTH BIGINT
    DECLARE @DAYOFNEXTMONTH BIGINT
    DECLARE @PAYMENTTYPES BIGINT
    DECLARE @NOOFDAYS BIGINT

    SELECT @PAYMENTTYPES = PAYMENT_TYPES
        ,@NOOFDAYS = NUMBER_OF_DAYS
        ,@DAYOFMONTH = DAY_OF_MONTH
        ,@DAYOFNEXTMONTH = DAYS_AFTER_DUE_DAY
    FROM XC_PAYMENT_TERMS_MASTER
    WHERE TENANT_ID = @TENANTID
        AND PAYMENT_TERM_ID = @PAYMENTTERMID

    DECLARE @DIFFERENCE BIGINT = ISNULL(@DAYOFMONTH, 0) - ISNULL(@DAYOFNEXTMONTH, 0)
    DECLARE @DUEDATE DATETIME
    DECLARE @ACTUALDUEDATE BIGINT
    DECLARE @CALCULATEDDATE DATETIME

    IF @PAYMENTTYPES = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @DUEDATE = DATEADD(dd, @NOOFDAYS, @INVOICEDATE)
    END
    ELSE IF @PAYMENTTYPES = 2
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @LEAPYEAR TINYINT = IIF(DATEPART(dd, (
                        EOMONTH(CONCAT (
                                DATEPART(yyyy, @INVOICEDATE)
                                ,'0201'
                                ))
                        )) = 29, 1, 0)

        IF @DIFFERENCE <= 0
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @STARTINGDATE DATETIME
            DECLARE @NEWDATE DATETIME
            DECLARE @NEXTMONTH DATETIME

            IF 1 = @LEAPYEAR
            BEGIN
                SET @STARTINGDATE = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @INVOICEDATE), 0)
                SET @NEXTMONTH = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @STARTINGDATE)

                IF 1 = DATEPART(MONTH, @INVOICEDATE)
                BEGIN
                    IF @DAYOFMONTH = 30
                    BEGIN
                        SET @DUEDATE = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, 2, @INVOICEDATE)), 0)
                    END
                    ELSE IF @DAYOFMONTH = 31
                    BEGIN
                        SET @DUEDATE = DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, 2, @INVOICEDATE)), 0))
                    END
                    ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        SET @DUEDATE = DATEADD(DAY, @DAYOFMONTH - 1, @NEXTMONTH)
                    END
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @DUEDATE = DATEADD(DAY, @DAYOFMONTH - 1, @NEXTMONTH)
                END
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @STARTINGDATE = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @INVOICEDATE), 0)
                SET @NEXTMONTH = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @STARTINGDATE)

                IF 1 = DATEPART(MONTH, @INVOICEDATE)
                BEGIN
                    IF @DAYOFMONTH = 29
                    BEGIN
                        SET @DUEDATE = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, 2, @INVOICEDATE)), 0)
                    END
                    ELSE IF @DAYOFMONTH = 30
                    BEGIN
                        SET @DUEDATE = DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, 2, @INVOICEDATE)), 0))
                    END
                    ELSE IF @DAYOFMONTH = 31
                    BEGIN
                        SET @DUEDATE = DATEADD(DAY, 2, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, 2, @INVOICEDATE)), 0))
                    END
                    ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        SET @DUEDATE = DATEADD(DAY, @DAYOFMONTH - 1, @NEXTMONTH)
                    END
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @DUEDATE = DATEADD(DAY, @DAYOFMONTH - 1, @NEXTMONTH)
                END
            END
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @SDATES DATETIME = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @INVOICEDATE), 0)
            DECLARE @NMONTH DATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @SDATES)

            IF DATEPART(DD, @INVOICEDATE) > @DIFFERENCE
            BEGIN
                IF @DAYOFMONTH > 30
                    AND DATEPART(DD, @INVOICEDATE) <> @DIFFERENCE
                BEGIN
                    SET @DUEDATE = DATEADD(s, - 1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @NMONTH) + 1, 0))
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @DUEDATE = DATEADD(DAY, @DAYOFMONTH - 1, @NMONTH)
                END
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                IF @DAYOFMONTH > 30
                    AND DATEPART(DD, @INVOICEDATE) <> @DIFFERENCE
                BEGIN
                    SET @DUEDATE = DATEADD(s, - 1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @NMONTH) + 1, 0))
                END
                ELSE IF @DAYOFMONTH > 30
                    AND DATEPART(DD, @INVOICEDATE) = @DIFFERENCE
                BEGIN
                    SET @DUEDATE = DATEADD(s, - 1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @SDATES) + 1, 0))
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @DUEDATE = DATEADD(DAY, @DAYOFMONTH - 1, @SDATES)
                END
            END

            IF 1 = @LEAPYEAR
            BEGIN
                IF 1 = DATEPART(MONTH, @INVOICEDATE)
                    AND DATEPART(DD, @INVOICEDATE) <> @DIFFERENCE
                BEGIN
                    IF @DAYOFMONTH > 29
                    BEGIN
                        SET @DUEDATE = DATEADD(s, - 1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @NMONTH) + 1, 0))
                    END
                END
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                IF 1 = DATEPART(MONTH, @INVOICEDATE)
                    AND DATEPART(DD, @INVOICEDATE) <> @DIFFERENCE
                BEGIN
                    IF @DAYOFMONTH >= 29
                    BEGIN
                        SET @DUEDATE = DATEADD(s, - 1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @NMONTH) + 1, 0))
                    END
                END
            END
        END
    END

    RETURN @DUEDATE
END
```